# How can I create a toggle button using keyboard controls?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events, accessibility

I have a simple information button. When this button is clicked, it opens an information text box, when you click that button again, that information box goes away, or 'toggles off'.

I'm trying to have the same behavior using a keyboard alternative. As of now, the information button again, opens the information text box when I hit the "enter" key. However, when I hit the enter key a second time, the information box doesn't toggle off, it remains displayed.

Current code:

```
//HTML
    <h2 class="tile-header">CCIR</h2>
        <span> 
            <img
            role="button"
            id="cis-info-button"
            aria-labeledby="Information for ccir Summary"
                ng-click="vm.showHelp()"
                ng-keydown="vm.keyHelp ($event)"
            class="info-icon"
            ng-src="{{infosrc_ccir}}"
            alt="ccir Summary Information"
            width="10" height="10">
        </span>      

//JS

  function showHelp()
    {
        var helpConfig =
            {
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'scripts/tiles/ccirSummary/views/ccirSummaryInfo.html',
                size: 'ccir-summary-help'
            };
        $modal.open(helpConfig);
    }

    function keyHelp(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.charCode === 32)
        {
            showHelp();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a URL to see this in action?

Answer (score 1):

Without a URL to test it, I am suggesting two things to try:

1. I don't see anything here where you move the focus to your button. Without getting focus, the button is not fired. That means you have to listen for the key press on the entire document.
2. Use a `<button>` instead of an `<image role=button>` as the `role` does not give it keyboard support (you have to script it all).

Most issues with modals (as you describe yours) come down to keyboard focus. I have a [modal example pen](http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/KdQEoJ) from another thing that shows focus management. When you activate the modal you will see you can hit the Enter key to open, close, open, close, and so on. That is possible just from managing the focus.

Comment: The focus is brought to the button using the tab key natively. 2. the ng-keydown gives it keyboard support as it fires the modal when the space/enter key is pressed

Comment: If you want a user to hit Enter to open, then hit Enter to close (no other actions in between), then you either need a function to close the modal (`$modal.close(helpConfig);`), or another button that does the job. Also, the ng-keydown is a poor proxy for using the right element (namely a `<button>`). Do you have a URL?

Comment: unfortunately not, im limited to what I can share, so it is a litte frustrating

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
       if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.charCode === 32) {
          showHelp();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately, looks like the same code I had previously, just in jQuery

Comment: Difference being that it is bound onto the document rather than the image. Thought that might have been your issue.